# Dynamically add an input to an HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

If we click the "Add" link, a new input should be added to the form.

Also, there should be link "Delete" near each added input. If we click on it, this input should be removed.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you try so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm struggling whether to vote to close this as a duplicate, even though it's not *exact*.  But what you're looking for appears to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157549/jquery-dynamic-creation-of-input-fields-based-on-the-number-selected-in-a-dropdow).  The main difference is that where they are binding to the `change` event for a `select` element:

```
$("#selectBox").change(function() {
```

you would instead bind to the `click` event of an anchor element (your "Add" link):

```
$("#addLink").click(function() {
```

The "Delete" link would work in a similar manner.  As the HTML is created for the new input, you'd also create the "Delete" link to go next to it before adding it to the DOM (the call to the `.html()` function in the referenced code).  You'll want to make sure that you give the added HTML a unique `id` (wrapped in a `div` with a unique `id` for example), as well as to the added "Delete" link.

Then, after it's added to the DOM, you'd add an event handler to the "Delete" link:

```
$("#deleteLink123").click(function() {
```

In this handler you'd reference the unique `id` of the container of what was added to the DOM and [remove it](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).  I'm sure there's a more elegant way to handle this by using the `.live()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and some more clever [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).  It would be interesting to re-factor something like this while trying to not be too clever so as to hurt ongoing support.

There are some additional considerations you'll want to keep in mind as you develop this:

1. The anchor tags are by default links, but it looks like you don't want them to link to anything.  You can link them to "#" but that's not really elegant.  You could remove the `href` attribute from them entirely, but then you'll also need to style them to visually behave like links.  Not difficult, but not intuitive either.  Why not buttons?
2. How the actual form behaves when handled by the server is up to you.  You can dynamically add elements to the DOM to your heart's content, but that may not help you on the server-side.  That's another question entirely, though.

Comment: You win the answer/question quality ratio prize for the day.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: It's a far cry from the much coveted Reversal badge, but I'll take it :)

Comment: Just 12 more to go! (oops, it's retired now)