# jquery - adding dynamic form based on dropdown values

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to create form based on the dropdown values.
i followed this tutorial

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157549/jquery-dynamic-creation-of-input-fields-based-on-the-number-selected-in-a-dropdo)

but it didn't work for me.

any help would be appreciated

JQ example

```
$("#selectBox").change(function() {
  var htmlString = "";
  var len = $("options:selected", this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlString += "<input type='text' class='email'>";
    htmlString += "<input type='text' class='name'>";
  }
  $("#outputArea").html(htmlString);
}
```

Comment: `didn't work for me` is just not enough to know your issues, could you explain the detail?

Comment: @xdazz  i created my own html to work with the JQ, but nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/WG68C/)

```
<select id="selectBox" >

    <option value=1>one</option>
     <option value=2>two</option>
     <option value=3>three</option>
    <option value=4>four</option>
     <option value=5>five</option>
     <option value=6>six</option>


</select>
<div id="outputArea"></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("#selectBox").change(function() {
  var htmlString = "";
  var len = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlString += "<input type='text' class='email'>";
    htmlString += "<input type='text' class='name'>";
  }

  $("#outputArea").html(htmlString);
})
```

I hope this will help you.