# How do I create multiple select option in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I want a form where a field is displayed if the
user selects a certain option. Like if the user
selects USA as a country, below it there should
be option to select a state from the country
and from the state select city. Same for
another country. Please, how do I implement
this? Am out of ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using Javascript or jQuery for this. Here is a similar SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157549/jquery-dynamic-creation-of-input-fields-based-on-the-number-selected-in-a-dropdo

Comment: You're talking about a dynamic select where the options in the second select are determined by what the users chooses in the first select?

Comment: Take a look at this blog entry. I've done a successful implementation, but there are some gotchas with routing and naming conventions that you'll probably be able to work out on your own.

Comment: Yea, dynamic form. Which blog entry?